# How do I perform machine learning classification that can output two simultaneous class predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, svm

amateur machine learning programmer here. I would like to perform a classification task wherein two simultaneous class predictions could occur.

For instance, in flowers image classification. Apart from being able to classify an image of a rose, or an orchid; I would also like to be able to classify if an image contains both roses and orchids simultaneously. Do I have to train my model to distinguish "Rose + Orchid" as an independent class?

Here's an example image of the task.

[image: Rose and Orchid Classification Problem]

Answer (score 3):

In scikit learn all classifiers which have `prob_a` function have your specification. This function returns the probability of assigning each class to the input `x`. Hence, you can use SVC, logistic regression, naive Bayes, random forest or any explained classifier in scikit learn (if you are seeking the specified classifier in scikit learn) based on your problem.

When you found the `prob_a` for each class, if the difference between two most probable class is near to each other, you can introduce the input with the two most probable class.

Answer (score 1):

This is called as multi-label classification problem. There are many approaches to solve this problem. Sklearn documentation about [multi-label classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

[An example with sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html)